# SC2153 (info): Possible misspelling: CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME may not be assigned

Tags: bash, shell, shellcheck

### Context

In a project I have two files in:

```
src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh
src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_root_certs.sh
```

The `make_ssl_project_certs.sh` contains the global variables for those two scripts (along with some documentation). A large fraction of those global variables are also used in `make_ssl_root_certs.sh`, and I would not want to create them twice.
Hence, I load both files from the `main.sh` in the root of the repository with:

```bash
source src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh
source src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_root_certs.sh
```

### Error message

However, when I run pre-commit, which runs shellcheck, I retrieve the following error message:

> C2153 (info): Possible misspelling: CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME may not be assigned. Did you mean ca_private_key_filename?

I include `-x` in shellcheck via pre-commit with:

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/shellcheck-py/shellcheck-py
   rev: v0.9.0.2
   hooks:
     - id: shellcheck
       name: check shell scripts with shellcheck
       args: ["-x"]
       files: ^.*\.(sh|bash|ksh)$
       types: []
```

### Approaches

I tried to resolve this issue by explicitly telling shellcheck to load the `src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh` file using in main:

```bash
# shellcheck source=src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh
source src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh
source src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_root_certs.sh
```

which did **not** yield a " SC1091 did not follow" error, however, it still yielded the SC2153 error the global (may) not be loaded, possible misspelling. So I also tried to tell shellcheck in the `make_ssl_root_cert.sh` file that it loads those globals from the `make_ssl_project_certs.sh` using:

```bash
# shellcheck source=src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh
```

Which yielded the same SC2153 error, and I also tried, in that `make_ssl_project_certs.sh` file:

```bash
# shellcheck source=make_ssl_project_certs.sh
```

Which yielded the same SC2153 error.

### Question

How can I prevent specifying the global variables for those two files twice, whilst keeping them in the `make_ssl_project_certs.sh` file and using them into the `make_ssl_root_certs.sh` file without manually disabling all shellcheck warnings on those Globals not being declared/having a potential misspelling (SC2153)?

In essence, how do I tell shellcheck that those globals are loaded from the `src/ssl_certs/make_ssl_project_certs.sh` file?

### Note

I use the global variables with capitalisation, and within the functions, I use the same variable name uncapitalised as locals.

Another undesirable solution would be to include:

```bash
# shellcheck disable=SC2153
```

in the top of the `make_ssl_root_certs.sh` file, because that could lead to ignoring actual mistakes.